# jquery version conflict in 1.8 to 1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to use a plugin in my website. but in website already used 1.8 version of jQuery and my plugin is 1.11 version. now its conflicting. please tell me what should i do. there is some types of error message come up
it says $. something is undefined
and it also says $.() is not a function.
so that it the problem please anybody help me.

Comment: So why not just use the newer version and remove the old one?

Answer (score 1):

You should update your website to use v1.11.2 and only load that version. There are virtually no API-breaking changes from v1.8 to v1.11, the only thing that was actually *removed* was the [`toggle(function,function)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event hookup (**not** the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) show/hide function, which is still there).

There *were* deprecations:

- [In 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)
- [In 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.9/)
- [In 1.10](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.10/)

...so best to check those lists and see if you're using any of those, but they haven't been removed yet (with the exception I mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is mostly backwards compatible.  Instead of loading v1.8 *and* v1.11, just load v1.11.  You're plugin will probably still work.

Comment: `v1.11` would be the newer version.